# how to delete 4 day file and folder using bash script in solaris

Tags: linux, solaris, solaris-10

```
find /home/bash/logs/ -type d -name "logs*" -mtime 0 -exec rm -rv {} \;
find /home/bash/fcubs/ -name 'logs*' -mtime 4 -daystart -delete
```

This is for Oracle Linux i need for solaris
thanks in advance

Comment: Note that on Unix, BSD--and Linux, too--they are "directories" and not the Windows concept of "folders" which is not the same thing.

Answer (score 0):

Try the second command w/o `-daystart` and `-delete`

```
find /home/bash/fcubs/ -name "logs*" -mtime 4 -exec rm -f {} \;
```

First should exec w/o problem in Solaris

Comment: not working on solaris

Comment: @МаруфСаматов, any error, what is wrong with the result?

Comment: @МаруфСаматов, tested on Solaris and work as charm.

Comment: it works find . -type f -name "logsE*" -mtime 3 -exec rm -f {} \;